# Django opening balances calculations

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a simple inventory app using Django. My project came to a stand still when I couldn't find a solution for calculating opening and closing balances on the fly/dynamically. I tried for days researching on the web but no progress yet. If anyone could help i will appreciate.

All I need is a query to calculate opening and closing balances dynamically.

My Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    buying_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class SalesSheet(models.Model):
    txn_date = models.DateField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchases = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

What I want after posting purchases and sales is an output like this

```
id  date        item  opening  purchases sales closing
 1  1-1-19      abc   10       20        5     25
 2  2-12-19     def   25       20        10    35
 3  3-1-19      abc   25       10        25    10
 4  4-1-19      def   35       10        30    15
 5  7-1-19      abc   10       0         0     10
 6  9-1-19      def   15       0         5     10
```

and so on.....

I am using item.quantity to store opening stock for the first time only.

Take into consideration that there will be different items and also back dated entries.

help me guys.

I tried adding these functions to my models and use them to display opening(opening_balance) and closing (closing_balance) balances. But the problem is that the loop is not working.

the idea was that if the loop worked then the opening stock will be updated by the new closing stock each time the loop runs.

```
class SalesSheet(models.Model):
    txn_date = models.DateField()
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    purchases = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sales = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def opening_balance(self):
        quantity = self.item.quantity
        items = SalesSheet.objects.all()
        for item in items:
            opening = quantity
            closing = opening + self.purchases - self.sales 
            quantity = closing
            return opening

    def closing_balance(self):
        quantity = self.item.quantity
        items = SalesSheet.objects.all()
        for item in items:
            opening = quantity
            closing = opening + self.purchases - self.sales 
            quantity = closing
            return closing
```

Comment: You need to do that in your views.py. show us your views.py file.

Comment: Look like you need OneToOneField not ForeignKey because you have one item for every SalesSheet. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi The Item Model is for adding items and their respective details. In this case I assume the items in Item Model are abc and def. The SalesSheet model is for all the items not just one item.

Comment: `sheet.item_set.all()` it will return all items under one SalesSheet.

Comment: Thank you @ManzurulHoqueRumi for your concern. But my issue in not how to dipsplay all the items. my problem is how to calculate the opening and closing balances based on sales and purchases. take a closer look at the output I provided. The opening and closing balances are not in the model. They need to be calculated dynamically/on th fly

Comment: Dear @Ahtisham, I have added a function in a model which I thought i could use to display the opening and closing balances. take a look since the loop is not working